# Mongoid Associations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In my problem I need posts to each belong to Category but I also want every post to be in a second category. Such that one post could be in "News" and another in "Sports" but they would both be in "Everything". Currently my associations are like this:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :home_category, :class_name => 'Category'
end
class Category
  include Mongoid::Category
has_many :articles
end
```

Currently the normal article.category works fine. However `article.home_category` sets on the Article object but does not reciprocate to Category object. So if I set `article.home_category=category` it works but if I do category.articles I get [].
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that my problem was that I was setting the category using a `before_save`, which incidentally turns out to not work out well when it is called on an unpersisted article. I fixed the problem by switching the `before_save` to an `after_create` filter and it then worked fine!
**In the end there was no problem with the Mongoid Associations, the problem was me.**

Answer (score 1):

the way you set up your relation, it's a 1:n relation between Article and Category ... that means that you can't have many categories for an article.

**You should change it to a n:m relationship**, see:

http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/n-n.html

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category
  include Mongoid::Category

  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

**Or you could try acts_as_taggable for Mongoid** :

http://abhishiv.tumblr.com/post/3623498128/introducing-acts-as-taggable-for-mongoid

Having two relations to Categories as you have in your example code is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I had tried HABTM relations but it didnt work, I will try again.

Comment: Also I realized, I need to make sure that it is ALWAYS in Everything while being allowed to change the other one.

Comment: I just tested it, does the same thing as before, the articles have categories but the everything category has no articles. Strange thing though, the other categories have their articles. Could it be that i'm using a before save filter to add the everything category?